# Angular 5 - communication between Components and Services

Tags: angular, service, components, communication

I use Angular 5.
The aim is to load data when Login is ok and to use these data in the other components.
The data are loaded by using Services Class with getActiveTasks Method and getStats Method.
Login Component :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent {

  constructor(private auth: AuthenticationService,
              private klinckServices: KlinckServices,
              private router: Router) { }

  loadData($event) {
    console.log('Authentification OK');
    let success;
    this.klinckServices.getActiveTasks(this.auth.getEcmUsername())
      .then((webScriptdata) => {
          console.log('KlinckSercices - loadData');
          success = webScriptdata;
          this.klinckServices.listTasks = success.data as ActiveTask[];
          this.router.navigate([this.klinckServices.getStats()]);
          console.log(this.klinckServices.listServices);
        },
        msg => {
          alert(msg);
          return '';
        });
   // this.router.navigate([this.klinckServices.loadData()]);
  }
}
```

Services Class :

```
@Injectable()
export class KlinckServices {

  listTasks: ActiveTask[];
  listServices: Stats [] = [];

  constructor(private apiService: AlfrescoApiService,
              private auth: AuthenticationService) {
    console.log('KlinckServices - constructor');
  }
  getStats(): string {
    this.listTasks.forEach((item, index) => {
      if (this.getServicesInListTasks(item.properties.wfvd_nomService) !== null) {
        if (! this.getServicesInListServices(item.properties.wfvd_nomService)) {
          const listLength = this.listTasks.filter(item2 => item2.properties.wfvd_nomService === item.properties.wfvd_nomService).length;
          console.log(listLength);
          const at: ActiveTask[] = [];
          for (let i = 0; i < listLength; i++) {
            at.push(this.listTasks.filter(item2 => item2.properties.wfvd_nomService === item.properties.wfvd_nomService)[i]);
          }
          this.listServices.push({
            data: at,
            count: listLength,
            service: item.properties.wfvd_nomService
          });
        }
      }
    });
    return '/dashboard';
  }
  getServicesInListServices( serviceSearch: string) {
    return(this.listServices.find( x => x.service === serviceSearch));
  }
  getServicesInListTasks( serviceSearch: string) {
    return(this.listTasks.find( x => x.properties.wfvd_nomService === serviceSearch));
  }
```

When the dashboard component is loaded , i need to retrieve these data :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit 
{
  @ViewChild(DataTableDirective) datatableElement: DataTableDirective;
  @Input() public klinckServices: KlinckServices;

  listTasks: ActiveTask[];
  listPatients: Patient[];
  listMedecins: Medecin[];
  listDocType: Typologie[];
  listServices: Stats [] = [];
  dtOptions: any = {};
  docNodeId: string;
  detailTaskId: any;

  constructor(private auth: AuthenticationService,
              public dialog: MatDialog,
              private http: HttpClient) 
  {
    console.log('DashboardComponent - constructor');
    this.listServices = this.klinckServices.listServices;
    console.log(this.listServices);
    this.getPatients();
    this.getMedecins();
    this.getDocumentType();
  }
```

But I get this error message in console : "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'listServices' of undefined"

So what is the best way to communicate between components and services ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should inject the service as you do in the `LoginComponent`

```
constructor(private klinckServices: KlinckServices
```

And you should also provide it to the module

```
providers: [KlinckServices]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can for instance:

1. Use **Singleton Service in Angular** and load data once during login
2. Load data not on login but on Dashboard init (OnInit method which interface U use in class definition - and ofcors you must inject you KlinkService in constructor to use it as **@CornelC** mention in his answer).

Additional Question for you: why you don't use Rxjs in your services (it is standard in angualar) on `KlinkService.getActiveTasks` (because you call it as promise) ?

Comment: because i read different ways by using '@Input' or Observable or '@Child', etc... I'm new in Angular so it's a little confuse for me

Comment: I update my question. Above.
Usually we not inject services using @Input - however this is good approach if you define Service Interface and create SEPAREATE components library for other projects (eg. in separate git repo) and that components lib need service which implements such interaface... - in that case use @ Input is acceptable

Comment: ok, if I understand '@Input' is a good way to define Interface but not to pass data , exact ?

Comment: no, usually @Input is for passing variables (parameters, objects) to component that we wanna READ in component. However, of corse we can put service and execute it methods - but it is not typical usage.